# Sliding menu javascript

Tags: javascript, menu, sliding

can anyone point me in the right direction to implement something like this please:
http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-sliding-menu/ but using javascript?

Thanks and have a nice day :),
C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at jcarousel: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Comment: does jcarousel work well for safari? its not looking right :/

Answer (score 2):

Agree - jQuery is excellent for this.

Try using this plugin for scrolling menus:
http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look at jQuery. It is just great. See http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

See this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790308/how-to-create-the-drag-and-slide-effect-from-this-website).

Points to http://www.azoffdesign.com/plugins/js/overscroll.

Answer (score 0):

I've used EasySlider before which is very easy to use. http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding